# Retrieve only a specific child from firebase realtime database into the Recyclerview

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have the following firebase database structure:
[image]

Where, under the user id child, I have created a child by **System date**.Date child will be created from system date and will be more than one.Suppose I have list of System date child which I will fetch from my firebase database and also show in Recyclerview?How can I achieve that?And what will be the data model class?

Comment: https://www.android-examples.com/show-firebase-database-data-into-recyclerview/

Answer (score 0):

you'll need to create your own adapter that:

- listens to onDataChange calls from Firebase
- keeps an internal copy of the data from Firebase
- informs the RecyclerView when the data changes
- creates view holders when those are needed
- binds data from the Firebase data to the view

The minimum I could come up with quickly is:

```
public static class MenuHomeAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MenuViewHolder> {
    ArrayList<Menu> items = new ArrayList<>();

    public MenuHomeAdapter(Firebase ref) {
        ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                items.clear();
                for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                    Menu menu = postSnapshot.getValue(Menu.class);
                    items.add(menu);
                }
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
                System.out.println("The read failed: " + firebaseError.getMessage());
            }
        });
    }

    public MenuViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, parent, false);
        return new MenuViewHolder(view);
    }

    public void onBindViewHolder(MenuViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Menu item = items.get(position);
        holder.getTitleView().setText(item.getTitle());
    }

    public int getItemCount() {
        return items.size();
    }
};
```